# 404 error when refering file location to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<body>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:white;
}
```

JS

```
body = document.querySelector('body')
rand10 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)

/*there are photos for every number, just didn't include them for sake of simplicity*/
if (rand10 == 1) {
    body.style.backgroundImage =`${url(./images/1.jpg)}`
}
```

Whenever i try to reference the images from the javascript file, dev tools always returns a 404 error, not found. The file structure is like so:

```
TOADOO
|+Images
|    =>(images here, listed as 1.jpg, 2.jpg ... nth.jpg)
|+Video
|    =>index.html
|    =>script.js
|    =>styles.css
```

(Summation) What is the format to tell javascript to reference another file location, without resulting in a 404 error

Comment: i can use a f string i belive

Answer (score 0):

```
body.style.backgroundImage =`${url(./images/1.jpg)}`
```

change

```
body.style.backgroundImage =`url('./images/${i}.jpg')`
```

Comment: I don't see an "img" directory in the OP's structure. Can you help to clarify?

Comment: Put your thinking cap on :)